# Android passing data between Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

My app's base is the Android provided template "bottom menu navigation"

I have an activity for user login (with google) and once the user logs in, I have an intent to call my MainActivty.

In my MainActivity I do AppBarConfiguration that works with a xml navigation (basically 3 fragments). When each bottom navigation button is clicked on, a different fragment is shown.

Android sets up the Java folder with a ui package and in there we have the 3 fragment classes along with their proper view models.

What I am trying to do, is pass the google values (i.e givenName and profile picture URL) from the login to my first fragment (dashboard fragment) that gets loaded when my MainActivity is created.

I used Bundle in the login class and used bundle getString in my dashboard fragment class within onActivityCreated.
The issue is, when my dashboard is displayed my Bundle is null.

I'm assuming the data gets lost somewhere in between login and dashboard fragment, while MainActivity is being created.

I do not believe I have to share any coding, I just need to know how to properly share data between activities and fragments and maybe viewmodels?

MY CODE:

LoginActivity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("GIVEN_NAME",loginItem.getGivenName());
                bundle.putString("PERSON_EMAIL",loginItem.getEmail());
                bundle.putString("PERSON_ID",loginItem.getmID());
                bundle.putString("PERSON_PHOTO",loginItem.getPhotoUri().toString());
                DashboardFragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

DashboardFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Get login intent
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        personGivenName = bundle.getString("GIVEN_NAME","No Name");
        personEmail = bundle.getString("PERSON_EMAIL","No Email");
        personID = bundle.getString("PERSON_ID","NA");
        personPhoto = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("PERSON_PHOTO",""));
    }//if
}//onActivityCreated
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

+++++++++++++++++++++ EDIT ++++++++++++++++++++
Created a new class Singleton (name it wtv you like)

```
public class SingletonUserInfo {
private String uID;
private String username;
private String uEmail;
private Uri uProfilePic;

//Singleton object
private static SingletonUserInfo INSTANCE = null;

// other instance variables can be here
private SingletonUserInfo() { };

public static SingletonUserInfo getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new SingletonUserInfo();
    }//if
    return(INSTANCE);
}//getInstance

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getuID() {
    return uID;
}

public void setuID(String uID) {
    this.uID = uID;
}

public String getuEmail() {
    return uEmail;
}

public void setuEmail(String uEmail) {
    this.uEmail = uEmail;
}

public Uri getuProfilePic() {
    return uProfilePic;
}

public void setuProfilePic(Uri uProfilePic) {
    this.uProfilePic = uProfilePic;
}
```

}//class

Then pass and get values from singleton this way:

```
SingletonUserInfo.getInstance().setuEmail(personEmail);
SingletonUserInfo.getInstance().getuEmail();
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Have you tried to use an intent? If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: You say that DashboardFragment  is " loaded when [...] MainActivity is created". Since it's unlikely that you pass an instance of DashboardFragment from LoginActivity to MainActivity, it seems that you first create a DashboardFragment instance in LoginActivity with the correct arguments Bundle but you don't actually do anything with it. Next, to show the Fragment in MainActivity, you create another instance of DashboardFragment in MainActivity without setting any arguments and display it. Am I guessing correctly so far?

Comment: @BömachtBlau yes that is what I think is happening..

Comment: Then you should first pass the Bundle from LoginActivity to MainActivity. If you need help please share more code, then we will be able to suggest an approach which is as close as possible to your already existing code

Comment: @BömachtBlau I was thinking about that but I don't feel like that is an efficient solution. I think the right way of doing it is K.Kotsi way (singleton and etc). Trying to do some more research on those subjects.

Comment: If you have the time and are ready to learn something new, that's even better :-) Just in case you need another link to get you going: the [guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) has been my starting point. That being said, since Bundles can still play a role in navigation graphs, it doesn't hurt to know how to work with them. From the problems you experienced with your first approach, just remember that an arguments Bundle is always assigned to a certain instance of the Fragment. It is not static in the Java sense (like "set once, retrieve everywhere").

Comment: @BömachtBlau thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the same data you shouldn't pass them through bundles. Passing data with bundles may slow down your application (Parcing data reduce performance). 
Instead you can try a combination of Singleton and ViewModels.
For Examble.

```
class LoginViewModel(
    private val userController : Controller
): ViewModel() {
    fun login(){
        userController.downloadUsers()
    }
    //some code...
    fun getUser(name: String): User{
        return userController.findUser(name)
    }
}
class DetailsScreenViewModel(
    private val userController : Controller
): ViewModel() {
    //some code...
    fun getUser(name: String): User{
        return userController.findUser(name)
    }
}

/**
 * Singleton class
 */
class Controller(){
    private var users = mutableListOf<User>()

    /**
     * Download users from a server.
     */
    fun downloadUsers(){
        users.add(User("Super User"))
        users.add(User("Good User"))
    }

    /**
     * Find a user.
     */
    fun findUser(name: String): User{
        return users.find { it.name == name } ?: throw NoUserFound()
    }
}
class NoUserFound(): Exception()

data class User(var name: String)
```

Comment: First of all i strongly recommend Kotlin instead of Java.
Do you know what a Singleton is?
Do you know what Dependency Injection is and how to use it?

Comment: Did some research and found your solution to work best! Though, your solution was a little more complex for my application, you still pointed me into the right direction! Thank you! Posted my solution in my post

Comment: If you want to "enhance" your code you should check mvvm with clean architecture. You can start with [this](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-apps-mvvm-with-clean-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

From within the activity you create the bundle, and assign it as an argument to the fragment.

```
Bundle mbundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
Fragmentclass mfrag = new Fragmentclass();
mfrag.setArguments(mbundle);
```

Then you retrieve it in your onCreateView within your fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String value = getArguments().getString("key");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did do that, I still get a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using static field or interface.

In your Activity class,

```
 HashMap<T> pojoMap =new HashMap<>();

private void setYourPojo(){
//Add your data to HashMap
 }

 public static HashMap<T> getYourPojo(){
 return pojoMap;}
```

And call it from your Fragment onCreateView

```
 HashMap<T> getYourData = Activity.getYourPojo();
```

**Note:** But if you use Asynchronous task, you should use Interface instead of static HashMap. Otherwise your HashMap data will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution here. I wanted to have common data for several activities. I made a new Base activity class that starts like this...

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {
    lateinit var basePref: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var basePrefEdit: SharedPreferences.Editor
    private var initFlag = 0
    ...
}
```

I then made all my activity class come from BaseActivity instead of AppCompatActivity. The companion object {...} is where you stick things in Kotlin where you want one version common to all instances. In this case I have got one set of preference reading objects, and a flag that we will set when we have set things up.